# how i add unmatched string into my else statement?

Tags: python, list

```
f1 = open("mysample.txt", "r")
f2 = open("mysample2.txt", "r")
# go with first line to read
    for line1 in f1:
            for line2 in f2:
                    if line1==line2:
                        print("SAME\n")
                    else:
                         print("Line is Note Matched" + str(line1) + str(line2))
           
     f1.close()
     f2.close()          
break
```

Comment: Please fix the indentation. You have `break` outside all the loops.

Comment: You can't loop through a file twice unless you call `f2.seek(0)` at the end of the inner loop.